# Applications deployed on cloud foundry consuming JMS / AMQP messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I have few applications which are consuming JMS messages and AMQP (Rabbit MQ) messages. I am moving my applications to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. However I want retain the messaging services outside cloud in the servers where they are currently hosted. Can Java apps deployed in PCF consume messages from topics / queues that are hosted outside the cloud env ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, surely they can. You need to take care of few things like firewall opening from cloud environment to the new external to cf server; making a connection successfully to the external server from your cf app.